# ArcGIS Pro : load Sketch into the Traverse tool without Parcel Fabric/COGO Enable

Tags: arcgis-pro, parcel, cogo, modify-features

In ArcMap, you can Load Sketch into the COGO Traverse tool and modify the survey calls (Metes and Bounds) of a polygon. It seems there is not an exact way to do that in ArcGIS Pro.

Every documentation keeps pointing to COGO enable this or that or Parcel Fabric.

In ArcMap the steps are:

1. Go into edit session
2. Select an existing feature
3. Right Click to edit vertices
4. Go to COGO window and right click on the empty area and load sketch

There it would populate the bearing and distance (Survey Calls). There are many GIS Specialists find this method useful, especially those who work in Real Property, Survey, and land acquisition.

We are planning to migrate to ArcGIS Pro in the future and the Traverse Tool in ArcGIS Pro just isn't helpful.  Are there any work arounds or solutions? We are currently not using parcel fabric, which seems very cumbersome.

Comment: From the Traverse pane, hitting the hamburger button at top right, you have the option to "Import Arcmap traverse file". Have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, Pro traverse is not conducive for running or loading extensive metes and bounds traverses as ArcMap was, as we are quickly learning. We have successfully been able to save and load prior traverses by using the 'hamburger' dropdown in the upper right hand corner of the traverse pane in Pro. Here you can import saved traverses, export traverses, and configure auto-pan features.

Just remember to enable indexing for quicker recalls if you have standard formatting  for saving traverses (we use Recorder's instrument # for deeds).

ArcMap was much quicker, as you could right-click inside your traverse to load, save, zoom to course, etc. Sad to see it go.

[image: Dropdown settings for traverse tool in Pro]